# Actual size in bytes occupied by an array of x datatype in java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory

How can "size in bytes" of a array of some datatype be determined?

What makes me ask this is a question from [this icse board question paper](http://www.respaper.com/icse/161/1039-pdf.html).

The question is as follows:

[image]

And the accepted answers by the board are `(space occupied by one of those data types*no of elements in the array)`

For example , one `int` array of `10` objects is said to take `4*10=40Bytes`

But my question is, wouldn't the array have to store it's length and indexes somehow(increasing it's size on memory), or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: That is just a answer what test checker's will understand. Your understanding is correct. But dare you write it in exam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is indeed correct. The official answer adopts a simplistic view of how arrays are stored.

There is a fixed cost associated with every object. Additionally, arrays need to keep track of their size and possibly other things.

The answer also ignores issues such as padding, alignment, etc.

Comment: So, there is no reliable way to determine it?

Comment: @AmithKK: You could use a memory profiler (VisualVM, YourKit, etc) to determine this at runtime. The answer would of course be JVM-specific.

Comment: @AmithKK: Again, depends on the JVM, on whether it's 32- or 64-bit, etc. I've not seen any official formulas.

Comment: @AmithKK these are not formulas, they are profiling tools, much like eclipse.

Comment: I know @Batty. You can't use a profiling tool during an exam ;)